# Reading serial and responding with Python

Tags: python, pyserial

Everyone, hello!

I'm currently using trying to communicate with my Arduino (whom is hooked up my Raspberry Pi through Serial) and using the information in my Python script on my Raspberry Pi.

That said, my Python script has to wait for the Arduino to report back it's data before I want the script to continue, although, I'm not entirely sure on how to do that.

This is what I've got so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import serial
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(20, GPIO.OUT) #green LED
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_UP) #green button

GPIO.output(20, True) #green ON

start = time.time()

while True:
        if (GPIO.input(16) == False):
                print "green button pressed"
                time.sleep(0.25)
                start = time.time()
                while (GPIO.input(16) == False):
                        time.sleep(0.01)
                if (GPIO.input(16) == True):
                        print "released!"
                        end = time.time()
                        elapsed = end - start
                        print elapsed
                        if elapsed >= 5:
                                print "longer than 5s"
                        else:
                                print "shorter than 5s"
                                ser.write("0")
                                while True:
                                       print ser.readline().rstrip()
                                       if ser.readline().rstrip() == "a":
                                               print "ready"
                                               continue
                                       if ser.readline().rstrip() == "b":
                                               print "timeout"
                                               break
                                       if ser.readline().rstrip()[0] == "c":
                                               print "validated: " + ser.readline().rstrip()[2]
                                               break
```

As you can see, I'm sending the number 0 to my Arduino, and wait for it to respond with a, which means it's ready. After which, when it has the data, it sends out the message "c", as a result, I need to wait for 2 different seperate messages.

I've tried to do this by having a loop and breaking it when I have what I need, but this doesn't work.

It currently does go into the loop, and it prints out the "a" message, but doesn't come back with the second message.

Any idea how to properly tie this loop?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked out well for me to keep my while, and escape the block until I get what i want:

```
loop = 1
while loop == 1:
      message = ser.readline().rstrip()
if message == "a":
      print "ready"
      continue
if message == "b":
      print "Timeout"
      loop = 0
if message[0] == "c":
      print "Validated: " + message[2]
      loop = 0
if message == "d":
      print "error, try again"
      loop = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

use functions

```
def wait_for(ser,targetChar):
    resp = ""
    while True:
       tmp=ser.read(1)
       resp = resp + tmp
       if not tmp or tmp == targetChar: 
          return resp

first_resp = wait_for(ser,'a')
second_resp = wait_for(ser,'c')
while not second_resp.endswith('c'):
    print "RETRY"
    second_resp = wait_for(ser,'c')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm afraid it looks to be a little bit over my head. Can you explain what's going on here?

Comment: it reads a byte at a time until it gets the `targetChar` and returns it all ... if it encounters a timeout for a requested byte .... it just returns what it has so far... by isolating behavior that is repeated into functions you can then just focus on the part thats problematic ...